# jquery register event on hyperlinks inside the div

Tags: jquery-ui

I wanted to apply events on hyperlinks under Id's with name "topicColumnTemplate". below is the HTML snippet and I am syntax => `$('[id^=topicColumnTemplate] a').click(function() { // do operation});`

But events are not getting applied, Links are generated dynamically if i use after once all the dom is populated using link id through syntax  => `$('[id^=link]').click(function() { // do operation});` it WORKS

What is wanted is in javascript intialization wanted to use above first syntax where in using the ul id which is already present in DOM & is not generated dynamically. Just giving div id of ul i.e [id^=topicColumnTemplate] works but it is getting applied all around the ul block which causes function invokation every where around the block & I need function gets invocated only when

**** replace "-"  with "<" for html

```
<ul id="topicColumnTemplate1" class="listcol ">
    <li id="row_0" class="listrow ">
        <a id="link_0" class="listtopic">user1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="row_1" class="listrow ">
        <a id="link_1" class="listtopic">user2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="row_2" class="listrow ">
        <a id="link_2" class="listtopic">user3</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="topicColumnTemplate2" class="listcol ">
    <li id="row_0" class="listrow ">
        <a id="link_0" class="listtopic" href="#">user1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="row_1" class="listrow ">
        <a id="link_1" class="listtopic" href="#">user2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="row_2" class="listrow ">
        <a id="link_2" class="listtopic" href="#">user3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use live function. This will apply the event hander for elements created later i.e:

```
$('[id^=topicColumnTemplate] a').live("click", function(){
  // do operation
});
```